# Merge overlapping portions from two polygons to one or the other using FME

Tags: merge, overlapping-features, fme-form, fme-transformer

I have a shapefile with many polygons, of which some portions overlap. When I use the AreaGapAndOverlapCleaner, it disconnects the overlapping portion, but makes it an independent feature with data of either polygons, ie now I have two polygons with same data.

What I want is, the overlapping portion to be merged with any of the polygon feature. How do I do this?

Comment: Not sure of your version of FME (Flow) but you should be able to do this with http://docs.safe.com/fme/2019.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/areaonareaoverlayer.htm see Choosing a Spatial Transformer for comparison Transfomers.

Comment: @Mapperz No, i think it works just as the overlap and gap claner. it converts the overlappiing regon to a new feature. what i want is to merge this overlapping region to one of the polygons.

Answer (score 0):

What version of FME are you using? And what parameter settings? By default, when I place two overlapping polygons, the overlap gets assigned to one or the other.

In my example, I just created a polygon (with Creator) as 0,0 0,10 10,10, 10,0 0,0. Then I created a copy by putting it into an Offsetter, offsetting by x=8, y=1. Then run both the Creator and Offsetter into an AreaGapAndOverlapCleaner. With the tolerance set to Automatic, I get the polygon dissolved into one part or another.

The other way to do it, with the results of your workspace, add a Dissolver transformer and group-by with an attribute the 2 polygons with the same data have in common (but other features won't). That way it will dissolve them together.

But I still think the AreaGap..etc should still work the way you expect.